# How to maintain my component(<MainImage>) and Flatlist component scrollable? React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I have this particular component above a Flatlist which renders my cards, and I want to make them both scrollable. I tried to nest them with a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView>
    <MainImage/>

    <FlatList />
 </ScrollView>
```

It works but my flatlist lost its ability to constrain memory, since I have a lot of data to render the app lags till crash.

[image]

If remove the ScrollView from my MainImage component it gets stuck on the screen and the cards scrolls behind it which is not cool.

```
<View>
   <MainImage/>

   <FlatList/>
</View>
```

[image]

How do I do to both components be able to scroll without losing performance?
obs: I'm using version 0.55 of react native

Comment: You should use `ScrollView`, then only you can the whole content scrollable. Share the code to see how you are using Flatlist. Flatlist is meant to handle lot of data

Answer (score 0):

You can also use collapsible navbar above the flatlist rather than using separate MainImage Component. People are doing that and example is given in this link (https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-collapsible-navbar-e51a049b560a)

Comment: Thanks but i had some problems using animations flatlist. I just solve the problem using [ListHeaderComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent)